# How to disable toolbar/searchbar on Chromedriver on Python

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find the right configuration to automatically hide/remove the "Always show toolbar in full screen" on Chromedriver launch

This is what i have so far.

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars") # removes a warning
chrome_options.add_argument("--kiosk")#open in full screen
```

But there is a grey bar that stays there in full screen mode (Shown in image) that only disappears when I uncheck "Always show toolbar in fullscreen"

Please let me know if you have any ideas. i've been looking for a solution here but can't find one related.

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugq1S.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just launch it in `application` mode by adding next argument:

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--app=https://www.google.com")
```

This `url` (https://www.google.com) is just an example so use one you have.

Comment: Thank you! it worked for the first tab then when i open using another tab using 

    browser.execute_script('''window.open("about:blank", "_blank");''')

the second tab will not be in app mode. anyway to force it throughout all tabs?

Comment: Not sure that you can do it for a new tab. As a workaround, you could work in the same tab or create another instance of webdriver.